# In Armoury v Delamirie, how did the claimant prove that he had visited the jeweller’s shop with a gem in the piece?

Tags: england-and-wales, common-law, legal-history

The [case](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armory_v_Delamirie) was before most traveled about with cameras in their pockets, and yet it seemed to turn on the noted questions of law rather than the obvious question of fact that may arise where the jeweller’s apprentice may be expected in such circumstances to deny that there ever had been any gems in the piece brought to him in the first place. Suing the apprentice’s master under superior respondeat seems to add yet another layer of hearsay precarity to the factual claim and it seems very difficult for the claimant to establish the presence or existence of the valuable gem in the first place, much as a cop who plants by sleight of hand some drugs or other contraband in a suspect’s car/bag and then attests that it was there in the suspect’s belongings all along has no real falsifiability of his claim and it just had to be trusted.

Answer (score 3):

### He testified to that (probably)

The case was in 1722 so no one “travelled about with cameras” because they wouldn't be invented for another 150 years. However, courts are quite comfortable dealing with evidence that isn’t photographic in nature.

While we don’t know the [specifics](https://moglen.law.columbia.edu/twiki/bin/view/EngLegalHist/ArmorieDelamirie#:%7E:text=Evidence%20introduced%20in%20Armory%20v,of%20his%20stock%20by%20auction.) of the evidence introduced, we know the court was satisfied that there had been jewels in the piece when the plaintiff handed it to the defendant’s apprentice:

> Armory is considered “one of the first instances of spoliation of evidence. Under this evidentiary rule, courts presume that evidence a party has concealed or destroyed would have been injurious to their case, based on the interpretive canon omnia praesumuntur contra spoliatorem, (all things against the spoliator of the evidence). See Ariel Porat, Liability Under Uncertainty: Evidential Deficiency and the Law of Torts 11 (2001); Margaret M. Koesel et al, Spoliation of Evidence ix-x (2006).

It may be that the issue was never contested; that is, the parties agreed that there had been gems in the piece. Or, possibly more likely, the court heard the testimony of the chimney sweep and the apprentice and decided that it preferred the former over the latter. The surviving documents don't tell us.

Notwithstanding, the court decided there was a jewel and that, because the defendant was in a position to produce it but didn’t, the court was entitled to draw the conclusion that it was of the “first water” i.e. of the most valuable kind.

Answer (score 1):

It is a mystery.

> I’ve tried to find out more information about [Armory v. Delamirie], but so far I’ve got nowhere. I’m still trying. But the trouble is that if the people in the case are poor, they tend to leave no trace in historical records. So if you do a case involving fairly wealthy people, you often find information. It’s easier to find information in the nineteenth century, because there are extensive newspaper reports. They often give very detailed accounts of litigation, so you get a lot of information from them, but the further back you go, the more difficult it gets. . . It’s such a strange case. I mean, here’s this chimney sweep boy, they were the lowest of the low, somehow suing – who paid for his lawyer? He’s suing the most distinguished silversmith of the early eighteenth century. The defendant’s work now sells for a million dollars an item. And yet we don’t know anything about how the case happened . . .I’ve [tried to get information on the case] intermittently for years, but I haven’t gotten anywhere. History is sometimes just hopeless. Sometimes you just have to give up.

- Legal historian A.W. Brian Simpson quoted by: https://moglen.law.columbia.edu/twiki/bin/view/EngLegalHist/ArmorieDelamirie